# How to remove a RStudio user

Tags: rstudio-server

I need to remove a user from RStudio-server. How can I do that? I have read the RStudio server administration [guide](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-server/rstudio-server-pro-0.98.507-admin-guide.pdf) thoroughly; however, did not get the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

RStudio Server doesn't have its own user system; it uses the same list of users as the Linux system on which it is installed. It's likely that you just need to remove the user from the RStudio Server system, using e.g. the `userdel` command.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel

If you want to allow the user to log in to the system, but don't want them to be able to log in to RStudio Server, then you can restrict access to a specific user group as follows:

http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/authenticating-users.html#restricting-access-to-specific-users

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I would accept the answer, however, I don't have enough reputation  :(